# Determine if all object properties are equal

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating the boolean `hasMultipleCoverageLines` to determine if different `coverageLineName` values exist on the items within `coverageLines`. Is there a way to simplify this expression so i don't have to explicitly check for each `coverageLineName`?

```
this.hasMultipleCoverageLines = !this.coverageLines.every((x) => x.coverageLineName === "Medical")
        && !this.coverageLines.every((x) => x.coverageLineName === "Dental")
        && !this.coverageLines.every((x) => x.coverageLineName === "Vision")
        && !this.coverageLines.every((x) => x.coverageLineName === "Life");
```

Comment: Are those four values the only possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) will enforce uniqueness. Put the names in a set, and see if the count > 1.

```
let names = this.coverageLines.map(x => x.coverageLineName);
let set = new Set(names);
this.hasMultipleCoverageLines = set.size > 1;
```

With this `["Dental", "Dental", "Dental"]` will produce a set of size 1, but `["Dental", "Vision", "Dental"]` will produce a set of size 2, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You could just check if any line is different than previous.

```js
const hasMultipleCoverageLines = (lines) => {
  return lines.some((line, i) => {
    return i > 0 && line.coverageLineName !== lines[i - 1].coverageLineName;
  });
};
```